# Adding Autoprefixer to a Svelte & Parcel project?

Tags: svelte, postcss, parcel, autoprefixer

I can't seem to get **autoprefixer** to work with **Parcel** and **Svelte**. I have the below code in a `'svelte.config.js'` file but it doesn't seem to be working even though it is not throwing any errors. Sass is being compiled correctly and I have a `.browserlistrc` file. Any help would be appreciated!

```
const sveltePreprocess = require('svelte-preprocess');

module.exports = {
  preprocess: sveltePreprocess({
    scss: true,  
    postcss: {
        plugins: [require('autoprefixer')]
    }
  })
};
```

I have the following devDependencies installed

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.7.3",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4",
    "parcel-plugin-svelte": "^4.0.5",
    "postcss": "^7.0.26",
    "postcss-load-config": "^2.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.24.2",
    "svelte": "^3.16.5",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^3.3.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`svelte.config.js` is for the editor - language server more specific, not for your `rollup` tools. Check the document [here](https://github.com/kaisermann/svelte-preprocess#with-rollup-plugin-svelte)

1. postcss.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    autoprefixer: {}
  }
}
```

2. .browserslistrc

```
> 1%
```

After you run `npm run dev` or `npm run build`, you will see those vendor-prefix in your css file or you can check it in your browser.